# Why Lord Kartik and Goddess Saraswati are unmarried?

Tags: saraswati, kartikeya

[image: Maa Durga]

Beside Maa Durga stands Lord Kartika, Lord Ganesha, Goddess Saraswati and Goddess Lakhsmi. While Lord Ganesha is married to a Banana Plant and Goddess Lakhsmi is married to Lord Narayan.

- Why is Lord Kartika and Goddess Saraswati unmarried?
- Is there any story or logic behind their remaining unmarried?

Comment: Do you mean Karthikeyan or Murugan when you say Lord Kartika?

Comment: @aniruddha Could you be more clear?

Comment: karthik, I am not talking about the Sount Indian Murugan or Karthikeyan , I am talking about North Indian Lord Kartik, see this: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110823041357AAou6M8

Comment: South Indians and North Indians may have different beliefs about him, but he's still the same god.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Neither one of them is unmarried.**

Saraswati is the wife of Brahma the creator god; [here](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/10/13/57) is how the Srimad Bhagavatam describes Brahma:

> Lord Brahmā, **the lord of Sarasvatī**, was mystified. “What is this?” he thought, and then he was not even able to see. Lord Kṛṣṇa, understanding Brahmā’s position, then at once removed the curtain of His yoga-māyā.

Brahma also has a second wife Gayatri, by the way.

As far as Kartikeya goes, according to South Indian tradition he has two wives, Valli and Devasena.  Valli isn't really mentioned much in Hindu scripture.  But regardless of whether you accept South Indian tradition, Devasena is definitely described in Hindu scripture; [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03228.htm) is a description of the marriage of Kartikeya and Devasena from the Vana Parva of the Mahabharata:

> And considering that this being (Skanda) was undoubtedly destined to be the husband of this lady by Brahma himself, he had her brought there, dressed her with the best apparel. And the vanquisher of Vala then said to Skanda, 'O foremost of gods, this lady was, even before thy birth, destined to be thy bride by that Self-existent Being. Therefore do thou duly accept her lotus-like beautiful right hand with invocation of the (marital) hymns.' Thus told, he duly married her. And Vrihaspati learned in hymns performed the necessary prayers and oblations. She who is called Shashthi, Lakshmi, Asa, Sukhaprada, Sinivali, Kuhu, Saivritti, and Aparajita, is known among men as Devasena, the wife of Skanda. When Skanda became united to Devasena in indissoluble bonds of matrimony, then the gods of prosperity in her own personal embodiment began to serve him with diligence.

Comment: Does this devasena literally means deva(gods) sena(army)? because skanda or kartekya is god of war therefore it is righteous to marry devasena as so, is this all explains it?

Comment: @Creator Yes, Devasena literally means army of the gods.  So the idea is that the only one worthy of being the Devasena-pati, the pati (husband) of Indra's daughter Devasena, is the one who is capable of being the Deva-senapati, the senapati (general) of the gods.

Comment: What a word play.. Devsena means both, army of the devas as well as daughter of Indra.. and Karthikeya being *pati* of both.