# Is Kartikeya, son of Lord Shiva, still Chief Leader (Senapati) of Deva/Devta's army?

Tags: kartikeya

I know that Kartikeya was selected as a Chief Leader (Senapati) of Deva/Devta's army.

I want to know whether Kartikeya is immortal or not?
If yes, then is he still the Chief Leader(Senapati) of Deva/Devta's army ?

Comment: See my answer here for how he became the general of the gods: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/4144/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan thanks ,I found in your answer   how he became the general of the gods but my question is he is still  Chief Leader (Senapati) of Deva/Devata's army. ? and Imortal ?

Comment: Yes lord Murugan or katikeya is swami of devasena so he is senapati of deva army, he is immortal as in this answer  answered by Keshav see http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/238/do-gods-die-in-hinduism Btw why do you want to contact Devasenapati to know if he is still devasenapati?

Comment: @Yogi no I don't want to contact him , and I am not that lucky to meet him, but I want to gain knowledge of Hinduism ,  then I want to tell this to My family & friends they only go to temple for worshiping they don't know what our scripture said how amazing hinduism is , I want to aware people who don't know about hinduism thats why I raised the question is Hinduism SE for knowledge thanks for giving above link.

Answer (score 2):

When the question of immortality is raised for Kartikeya, I can only answer with respect what Sri Vaishnava tradition believes. In that view, Kartikeya is as immortal as his father Shiva.

There are different destruction pattern followed for each loka (Bhu: Bhuva: Suva: etc till Sathya lokam) at the end of chathuryugas. There are many Q&A involved discussing about when does the sathya loka will be destructed and that may be referred to.

In this case at the end of destruction of sathya loka none other than the paramapursha exist. In my understanding that includes, Bramha, Vishnu and Sivha, Karthikeya and Ganesha.  In that line vishnu is also one of the avathar of the paramapursha, Paramapadhanathan.

So, if is human's mortality is used as the yardstick, then Kartikeya can be considered as immortal.

I cannot site a source for this as it is not documented and even it is so, it is just going to be a belief of some author.

Comment: Answers on this site are supposed to be backed up with sources (preferably scripture), so please try to find sources.  By the way, when you say Vishnu dies, you mean Vyuha Vasudeva, right?  Because "Vishnu" is a term used for both Vyuha Vasudeva and Para Vasudeva (whom you call Paramapadanathan).

Comment: That's correct. I will surely hunt for the references.