# How can Skanda and Ganesha marry Brahma's daughters?

Tags: brahma, ganesha, parvati

> I am a daughter of Prajapati (the lord of all creatures, Brahma) and my name is Devasena. My sister Daityasena has ere this been ravished by Kesin. We two sisters with our maids habitually used to come to these Manasa mountains for pleasures with the permission of Prajapati. And the great Asura Kesin used daily to pay his court to us. Daityasena, O conqueror of Paka, listened to him, but I did not. Daityasena was, therefore, taken away by him, but, O illustrious one, thou hast rescued me with thy might. And now, O lord of the celestials, I desire that thou shouldst select an invincible husband for me.
>
> O hero with long arms, I am Avala (weak) but my husband must be powerful. And by the potency of my father's boon, he will be respected by gods and Asuras alike. That manly and famous and powerful being devoted to Brahma, who is able to conquer all the celestials, Asuras, Yakshas, Kinnaras, Uragas, Rakshasas, and the evil-minded Daityas and to subdue all the worlds with thee, shall be my husband.
>
> The Performer of a thousand sacrifices then thought of Devasena, whom he has rescued before. And considering that this being (Skanda) was undoubtedly destined to be the husband of this lady by Brahma himself, he had her brought there, dressed her with the best apparel. And the vanquisher of Vala then said to Skanda, 'O foremost of gods, this lady was, even before thy birth, destined to be thy bride by that Self-existent Being [Brahma]. Therefore do thou duly accept her lotus-like beautiful right hand with invocation of the (marital) hymns.' Thus told, he duly married her.

link:[Wives of Lord Kartikeya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4100/wives-of-lord-kartikeya/4144#4144)

It is also said that Siddhi and Biddhi are the daughters of Brahma as per Ganesha Purana.

Now,it is known that Sati,who is Daksha's daughter,is Brahma's grandaughter.Hence,any daughters of Brahma is Sati's aunties.This means that Devasena,Siddhi and Buddhi are Sati's aunties and hence,the grandmothers of Ganesha and Skanda.In that case,how can Ganesha and Skanda marry their own **grandmothers**?

Comment: You are applying rules meant for humans on divine beings.That is what is creating such erroneous situations.While human beings can only reproduce sexually, divine beings are often created asexually .Take for eg the manasa putras/putris(who are born out of mind).Daksha in particular was created from Brahma's thumb i.e asexually.So should the same human rules apply on them?

Comment: @Rickross Are you saying that the rules of mortals do not apply to the divine?Well,mortals think incest is wrong as it produces deformed babies.At least that is the main point.But,if Devasena/Buddhi/Sddhi were their grandmothers,wouldn't they have also helped Parvati take care of them?Wouldn't each of them love each other in a parent/child manner?Then hoew can they even **think** of marrying them?

Comment: Well rules that apply to mortals will not apply as it is to the divine beings.This is true.

Comment: @Rickross What about the last bit

Comment: @Rickross If that is the case,why did Yama refuse Yami when she came to him

Comment: Yama and Yami were born to same mother. So they are brother and sisters.

Comment: @Sree Charan I don't see your point...

Comment: Yama and Yami are born sexually unlike Daksha from Brahma.

Comment: @Sree Charan And so? That doesnt make any difference, does it?

Comment: Some say Ganesha is married to "Kolabou" while some say he is married to riddhi and biddhi. Kartikeya is believed to not have married but in south India he has 2 wives named devasena and Valli. But I personally believe kartikeya is a bachelor as in south India they say he is the second child. But thst is not possible as his birth was to kill Tarkasur and Parvati became a mother on the first place to kill that demon.